# Styling the Extended Toolkit BusyIndicator

Tags: c#, wpf, busyindicator, wpf-extended-toolkit

I'm looking to style the `BusyIndicator` so it looks something along the lines of this;

[image]

At the moment my busy indicator does not take up the whole `Window` that it is placed in too, which I would like it to do. My current `BusyIndicator` looks like this;

[image]

Has anybody had success with styling the `BusyIndicator`? I've had a look at the example on the Extended Toolkit website however it does not result in what I would like the indicator to look like.

Answer (score 1):

This is a part of `BusyIndicator`'s control template:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="busycontent">
                     <ContentPresenter.Content>
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
```

`busycontent` element is a rectangular region, which holds "Please wait" (default `BusyContent`) and progress bar. As you can see, alignment values for `Grid` are hard-coded and they make grid to be centered.

You have two options:

- apply your own control template (you can base it on Xceed's one);
- make your own `BusyIndicator` (since it is based on overlays concept, it is not so complex task).